# selenium webdriver - how to handle ajax calls

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have been reading about how to handle AJAX in Selenium webdriver. There are a lot of solutions. Is there one best and correct solution?

The solutions I have read about so far are:

1) Using thread sleep
2) waitFor method
3) ExpectedCondition
4) FluentWait
5) PresenceOfElementLocated

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reliable solution to handle ajax components(as used in my case) is to wait for the element to be visible on the page using waitUntil() API call of webdriver.

Otherwise threadsleep() like solution is not at all recommended to handle Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this and it itself waits works fine.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Thanks try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, this is what I recommend. You can control exactly how often polling happens.

```
// poll every 1/3 second for 3 seconds
int timeout = 3; // seconds
int pollFreq = 3; // times per second

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout, 1000/pollFreq);
// to be safe, test (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) here
JavascriptExecutor executor = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);

// Check to see if jQuery is available first
Boolean hasJquery = (Boolean) executor.executeScript("return !!window.jQuery");
Boolean hasActive = (Boolean) executor.executeScript("return typeof window.jQuery.active === \"number\"");
if (hasJquery && hasActive) {
    // Wait for JS AJAX calls to complete...
    wait.until((ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) driver -> (Boolean) executor
            .executeScript("return window.jQuery.active === 0"));
    // JS AJAX calls completed.
    // Good idea to add a timing report here for troubleshooting.
}
// else jQuery/active-prop not available, continue
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try the Apache Http Client if you want to perform make ajax requests from your test.  Here is some Groovy code that does this.  Chances are not high that you are using Groovy, but this should still be informative regarding Get & Post in general with the client.

```
import groovy.util.Expando
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.Header
import java.net.URLDecoder
import com.auto.utils.crypto.Crypto

class ClientHttps {
private HttpClient client = null
private BufferedReader br = null
private String cookieString = ""
private crypto = new Crypto()
def log
public ClientHttps(log) {
    this.log = log
    client = new HttpClient();
    client.getParams().setParameter("http.useragent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2")
}
public Expando get(String url) {
    def startTime = System.nanoTime()
    GetMethod method = new GetMethod(url)
    Expando returnData = new Expando()
    try {
        log.info("cookieString = " + cookieString)
        method.addRequestHeader("Cookie", cookieString)
        method.addRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json")
        int returnCode = client.executeMethod(method)
        log.info("returnCode = " + returnCode)
        if (returnCode == HttpStatus.SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) {
            log.error("The Get method is not implemented by this URI")
        } else {
            if ((returnCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) && (returnCode != HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY))
                assert false, "Bad Response Code"
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(method.getResponseBodyAsStream()))
            String readLine;
            while(((readLine = br.readLine()) != null)) {
                log.info(readLine)
            }
            Header [] respHeaders = method.getResponseHeaders()
            respHeaders.each () {
                log.info(it.getName() + " = " + it.getValue())
                returnData.setProperty(it.getName(), it.getValue())
            }
        }
        def endTime = System.nanoTime()
        def duration = endTime - startTime;
        def seconds = (double)duration / 1000000000.0;
        log.info("Get took = " + seconds + " seconds (Get url = " + url + ")")
        return returnData;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.message, e)
        return null
    } finally {
        method.releaseConnection()
        if(br != null) try {
            br.close()
        } catch (Exception fe) {
            log.info(fe.message, fe)
        }
    }
}
public Expando post(Expando postData) {
    def startTime = System.nanoTime()
    PostMethod method = new PostMethod(postData.getProperty("url"))
    postData.getProperty("params").each() {method.addParameter(it.key, it.value)}
    Expando returnData = new Expando()
    try {
        int returnCode = client.executeMethod(method)
        log.info(returnCode)
        if(returnCode == HttpStatus.SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) {
            log.error("The Post method is not implemented by this URI")
        } else {
            if ((returnCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) && (returnCode != HttpStatus.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY))
                assert false, "Bad Response Code"
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(method.getResponseBodyAsStream()))
            String readLine
            while(((readLine = br.readLine()) != null)) {
                log.info("Response Data = " + readLine)
            }
            Header [] respHeaders = method.getResponseHeaders()
            respHeaders.each () {
                log.info(it.getName() + " = " + it.getValue())
                try {
                    returnData.setProperty(it.value.split("=")[0], it.value.split("=")[1])
                }
                catch (Exception exc) {
                    log.info("Could not split on equals sign = " + it.value)
                }
            }
        }
        def endTime = System.nanoTime()
        def duration = endTime - startTime;
        def seconds = (double)duration / 1000000000.0;
        log.info("Post took = " + seconds + " seconds (Post url = " + postData.getProperty("url") + ")")
        return returnData
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        log.info(exc.message, exc)
        return null
    } finally {
        method.releaseConnection()
        if(br != null) try {
            br.close()
        } catch (Exception fe) {
            log.info(fe.message, fe)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to test pages that make AJAX calls. Selenium must wait until those calls are complete before the page is ready. OP does not want to make AJAX calls from within his tests. As you point out, there would be no need for Selenium/Webdriver to be involved to test an AJAX call result. (I was not the downvoter but I'm sure this is why there is one.)